# Automatically create a new file inside a folder.

Tags: linux, automation, xubuntu

**Platform**: *nix/xfce/xubuntu/ubuntu-studio/14.04
Linux .... 3.13.0-24-lowlatency #47-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT .... x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Problem**: When I click 'create new folder' I want a blank file to automatically be generated inside the new folder. I want the new file to be named the same as the folder. 
I'm unsure how to even begin with this.....

Thanks in advance.

**Notes**: I'm not sure if this is the right exchange, I hope it is but if not please let me know which to post this too.

Comment: What's the rationale behind this?  Just curious.

Comment: you can write some bash script named, for example  "makedir" - and put a commands in it to create a folder (mkdir) and file (touch) in this folder as first argument, make this this script executable and put in in /bin/ folder. Run it as: makedir somename and you should get the folder and file in it as you want.

I dont think there is a way to do it via GUI - but via cli - it is very easy.

Comment: u can do it (with GUI) like this link after make what Max said.http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91876/is-it-possible-to-add-an-item-to-the-gnome-right-click-menu/91898?noredirect=1#comment138678_91898

Comment: @tink when I fiddle about with a projects or whatever I generally make a blank file for notes in the folder.